# Quarto not compiling: "file 'filepath' does not exist. problem with GDrive

Tags: google-drive-api, r-markdown, quarto

I am currently exploring and have been using RMarkdown before that for quite some time. Today, working in the office - after working with the file with computer at home yesterday - the qmd file does not compile any more. I get the following message:

```
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(cwd) :
  file 'G:\My Drive\etc' does not exist
Calls: .main -> execute -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

**It appears to be a problem with gdrive. when I save the file elsewhere, it does compile.**

I was expecting compilation.

I tried updating all related packages.